# Prove $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}| x^2+y^2+z^2>1\}$ is not connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Prove $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}| x^2+y^2+z^2>1\}$ is not connected

I have tried 2 open set A and B as follows: $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}| x^2+y^2+z^2>1\}=A\bigcup B$

$=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}| x^2+y^2+z^2>1,1-x^2-y^2<0\}\bigcup \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}| x^2+y^2+z^2>1,1-x^2-y^2\geq 0\}$. Then prove A,B is open set. But I have a hard time doing this, hope you help me

Comment: Isn't it the exterior of the unit ball in $\Bbb R^3$? I think it is connected.... or maybe I am missing something obvious?

Comment: @TitoEliatron Yes. If connected, you can prove it ?

Comment: What's your definition of "connected"? It is not difficoult to see that it is arc-connected

Comment: @TitoEliatron Def: X is connected is can not exist A, B open set and $A\bigcap B$ is empty: X=A$\bigcup$B

Comment: A good question would be to provide a proof of the connectedness of $S$ using OP definition (probably by way of contradiction).

Comment: @TitoEliatron I have a follow-up question: $\mathbb{R^3}\setminus \{(x,y,0):x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ is connected or not ?

Comment: @TitoEliatron I do not know you mean.Because z=0, why is a cylinder ?

Comment: Sorry, It is the  closed unit disk in the plane $z=0$.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Acording to you is $\mathbb{R^3}\setminus$ it is connected or not ?

Comment: It is arc-connected.Try a similar proof as those in my answer.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Acording to you is $\mathbb{R^3}\setminus \{(x,y,0):x^2+y^2=1\}$ is connected or not. I hope is not,

Answer (score 2):

Let call $S$ to your set.

**CLAIM**: Any point in $S$ can be arc-connected with $(2,0,0)$.

**PROOOF**: Let $u\in S$, then the segment from $u$ to $\frac{2u}{|u|}$ always lies in $S$. Now take any continuous path form $\frac{2u}{|u|}$ to $(2,0,0)$ lying in the sphere centered at $(0,0,0)$ with radius $2$ (this path also lies in $S$). Join the two paths and you're done.

**COROLLARY**: $S$ is arc-connected, so connected.

**PROOF** Take any two points $u,v\in S$. connect each point with $(2,0,0)$. You're done.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are trying to prove a false result. Try to draw $S$: it is the exterior of the unit ball and it is clearly "visually-connected". As connectedness has been invented to give a rigorous definition of "visually-connected", this would be a strange fact if $S$ was not connected.

To prove $S$ is connected, you can show:

- every path-connected topological space is connected
- $S$ is path-connected

The first statement is proven this way: suppose $X$ is path connected, and let $x\in X$. Suppose $f : X \to \{-1,1\}$ is continuous. We want to show that $f$ is constant. If $y \in X$, there exists a continuous path from $x$ to $y$ by path-connectedness, say $\gamma : [0,1] \to X$. Then $f\circ \gamma$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ which is connected and $f\circ \gamma$ is constant. This show that $f(y)=f(\gamma(1))=f(\gamma(0))=f(x)$. The previous being true for all $y$, $f$ is constant equal to $f(x)$. Hence, every continuous function from $X$ to $\{-1,1\}$ is constant, and $X$ is connected.

The second statement is proven by a simple drawing and a little bit of effort to write it mathematically.